# Is NAT loopback the only reason I can't view my own website from within my LAN?

Tags: router, dns, nat, loopback

I am new to this so apologies if this is the wrong place for such a question.

I'm testing out a simple "hello world" website hosted at home. As we have not been assigned a static IP address by our ISP I've set up a subdomain with a dynamic DNS provider to point at the home router - let's call this subdomain *mysubdomain.ddnsprovider.net*. I also have a domain which I own (and which was set up with a different provider than that to the dynamic DNS subdomain) - let's call that *mymaindomain.com*. A DNS CNAME record for *mymaindomain.com* is set up to point at *mysubdomain.ddnsprovider.net*.

I can successfully browse to *mymaindomain.com* and see my "hello world" page from anywhere outside of my home LAN - but if I browse to *mymaindomain.com* from any machine at home (i.e. within the LAN) I get "Server not found"/"web page not available" etc errors.

I understand from various searches that this looks like a NAT loopback issue and as such is likely best solved by getting a new router that supports NAT loopback. However, I can see my "hello world" site if I browse to *mysubdomain.ddnsprovider.net* from anywhere at all - including from within my LAN. From what (little) I understand about NAT loopback, I shouldn't be able to connect to a site hosted within my LAN via an external address (i.e. *mysubdomain.ddnsprovider.net*) at all if lack of support for NAT loopback by my router is the cause of the issue.

So, before I go out and buy a new router, my question is:

Is this definitely a NAT loopback issue (how can I confirm that)? And if so, what's the reason I can see my website from within the LAN via *mysubdomain.ddnsprovider.net*? If it isn't NAT loopback what is it likely to be and what's the best solution?

FWIW - I'm in the UK and am using a BT home hub 3 wireless router connected to a BT Openreach modem (Infinity fibre). Does anyone know whether the lack of NAT loopback support is inherent in the router, or modem, or both? - i.e. is replacing just the router likely to solve the problem or is it likely to persist unless I replace both of them (if that's possible).

Any light that anyone can shed on this and any advice would be very gratefully received.

Comment: Clearly not a loopback issue, more like a name resolution issue for your domain.

Comment: Thanks Sami.  If I enter mymaindomain.com here: https://cachecheck.opendns.com/ - it returns the correct IP across the board.  Would that still indicate a name resolution issue?

Comment: Try pinging mysubdomain.ddnsprovider.net and mymaindomain.com from inside. Some routers intercept dns-requests, and if the resulting ip matches the outside ip, it returns the inside ip instead.

Answer (score 0):

The BT HomeHub3 is a very poor router to try and attempt this normally very simple process on. NAT loopback works but ignores port 80 - Try to use another port for your website, (www.example.com:8000) and create a new service (port) and rule. If still no joy use another router which has proper working NAT loopback . The router should have PPPoE and use the username/password bthomehub@btbroadband.com / BT. I used a TP-LINK WRT-710N with openwrt and I could finally have my website working internally/externally.

The White BT boxes are normally quite trouble free (it's only a very simple modem anyway) but the routers cause so many issues.